# Dynamic decision networks

Tags: bayesian

I was wondering if anybody had some good references on dynamic decision networks,
is there a nice recent survey on this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been reading this books on BN and DDN and they  are very usefull.
Just follow the link and you will find more .
Enjoy!

["Artificial Intelligence: Modern Approach" textbook by Russell and Norvig](http://read.pudn.com/downloads134/ebook/572067/Bayesian%20Artificial%20Intelligence%20-%20Korb%20Nicholson.pdf)